# Select box with textboxes

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="count" name="count"/>
<div>
   <select id='canselect_code' name='canselect_code' multiple class='fl'>
        <option value='1'>toto</option>
        <option value='2'>titi</option>
        <option value='3'>tita</option>
        <option value='4'>titb</option>
        <option value='5'>titc</option>
        <option value='6'>titd</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' id='btnRight_code' value='  >  ' />
    <br>
    <input type='button' id='btnLeft_code' value='  <  ' />
    <select id='isselect_code' name='isselect_code' multiple class='fr'>
    </select>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var allowMove = 0;
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
    var value = $('[name=count]').val();
    var chosen = $('#canselect_code :selected').length;
    if(chosen == value){
        alert('1');
        $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
        allowMove = value;
    }
    else if(allowMove < value && allowMove < chosen){
        alert('2');
        $(this).prev('select').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
        allowMove += 1;
    }
    else
        alert("Not Allowed!");
    });

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
    allowMove = 0;
    $(this).next('select').find('option').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
});
```

I want the move-to-the-right-hand-side button to only move the number of elements selected by the user and it should match the number entered by the user in the textbox.
The left button moves all the values to the left select box whether selected or not.
The select box allows multiple values to be selected.

So how should I go about it?

EDIT:

```
var counter = 0;
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
    var value = $('[name=count]').val();
    var chosen = $('#canselect_code :selected').length;
    var tot = counter + chosen;
    alert(!(tot > value));
    if(chosen == value && counter != value) {
        counter = value;
        $('#canselect_code').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
    }
    else if(chosen < value && !(tot > value) && counter < value){
         $('#canselect_code').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
        counter+=chosen;
        alert(counter);
    }
    else {
        alert("Not Allowed!");
    }
});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
   counter = 0; $('#isselect_code').find('option').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
});
```

This is the new javascript code i've managed to create.

This works fine if the user selects one value at a time and clicks the move-to-right-hand-side button.

However i noticed that if the user entered the number 2 (for example) in the textbox and selects only one value from the select box and clicks the move-to-right-hand-side button it works fine. But in the second time if the user selects multiple values and clicks the move-to-right-hand-side button all the selected values go to the right hand side. Even though the alert displays false, the logic fails in validation of the else if statement.

What am i doing wrong here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys i got the problem.
In the scenario mentioned in the EDIT, It was running the first if statement the second time and appending the selected values to the right hand side select box.

The following is the new javascript that i created which works pretty well to suit my need.

```
var counter = 0;
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
    var value = $('[name=count]').val();
    var chosen = $('#canselect_code :selected').length;
    var tot = counter + chosen;
    var flag = true;
    if(tot > value)
        flag = false;
    alert(!(tot > value) + '\n' + tot);
    if(chosen == value && counter != value && flag) {
     counter = value;   $('#canselect_code').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
    }
    else if(chosen < value && flag && counter < value){
     $('#canselect_code').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
        counter+=chosen;
        alert(counter);
    }
    else {
        alert("Not Allowed!");
    }
});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
   counter = 0; $('#isselect_code').find('option').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you're asking - see http://jsfiddle.net/LcWf2/

I'm not sure what you were intending with the first "else" block in your original code, but it contradicts the request to only move the selected items if the number of items matches the "count" input, so I omitted it.

```
$('[id^=\"btnRight\"]').click(function (e) {
    var value = $('[name=count]').val();
    var chosen = $('#canselect_code :selected').length;
    if(chosen == value) {
        $('#canselect_code').find('option:selected').remove().appendTo('#isselect_code');
    } else {
        alert("Not Allowed!");
    }
});

$('[id^=\"btnLeft\"]').click(function (e) {
    $('#isselect_code').find('option').remove().appendTo('#canselect_code');
});
```